# watch function is not triggered for property Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I have a `properties` component, which contains some input props

```
props: ['activeObjectProps', 'canvas', 'fonts']
```

i need to watch `activeObjectProps` for changes, so here is wathcer

```
watch: {
    'activeObjectProps': {
        handler: function (newProps) {
            console.log('watch triggered');
        },
        deep: true
     }
}
```

in template i have following `v-for` loop:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 center-xs" v-for="font in fonts" @click="setFont(font)" :style="{fontFamily: font}">
    {{font}}
</div>
```

and finally `setFont` method

```
methods: {
        setFont: function (font) {
            //this.editFontModal.close();
            this.$set(this.activeObjectProps, 'fontFamily', font);
        }
    }
```

if i understood correctly, i should call `$set` function to set this reactive parameter, but this is not works. If i click on some font, `handler` function are not triggered. Of course if i just `this.activeObjectProps.fontFamily = font` - it doesn't work too. Can you give me an advice, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Vue?

Comment: @BertEvans "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vueify": "^9.4.1",

Comment: @BertEvans there is vue 2 syntax in my code. look here https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch i need to pass deep: true property

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or codepen demonstrating the issue?

Comment: At this moment no, unfortunately. I'll try to replicate and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what is different, but this works http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/oZGLoz?editors=1010

Comment: Sometimes the problem is in very unexpected place. The problem was in modal plugin, which i think incorrectly refresh content (dynamic vue content is in this modal). Anyway, thank you for your time!